# MvcScaffolding a new project and add it to the solution (Large Scale Generation)

Tags: model-view-controller, code-generation, t4, scaffolding

If I want to Large Scale Generation and define

Application = Framework (binary core components) + Generated Code + Custom Code

How would I go about creating code generation framework using scaffolding to generate multiple projects and associated files from some metadata (let's say a DSL model defined in a solution folder)

I know that I can use MvcScaffolding powershell cmdlets to add files to the current on another project.

I need to know if I can add a new project (Class library, Web appication) to the current solution from some kind of project template, apply source transformation and possibly merge some custom data. That would allow additional files to be added and I would prefer that both creation of the project and adding some files initially be done in one powershell line based on some input parameters (let say the name of some DSL model, XSD schema, XML data)

Could I just create a new solution and invoke some scaffolders? Are there scaffolders at a solution level?

I would like to have a scaffodling framework resembling software factories (Web service software factory). Any samples, ideas, articles?

Thanks
Rad

Answer (score 1):

**I don't see any reason why not.**

Your T4 templates can access [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and so do all sorts of fun VS automation, and of course the .ps1 powershell scripts can (I guess - I am no powershell guru) do pretty much anything you yourself can do on your box.

But out of interest why would you want to generate whole projects? i.e. are you sure that is time saving?